# How to visualize intrinsic/extrinsic camera parameters in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm working with OpenCV stereo vision and my calibration module is acting up. For debugging purposes, I'd like to visualize the camera parameters calibration is calculating, and I'm hoping to find some built in functionality to help with this. I'm looking for something akin to Matlab's [showExtrinsics()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/showextrinsics.html). Any suggestions/pointers to writing my own visualization? I was unable to find anything helpful in OpenCV docs.

My intrinsics matrix:

```
%YAML:1.0
M1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 4.6716183686593592e+02, 0., 3.4685206899619874e+02, 0.,
       4.6716183686593592e+02, 2.6460277614179995e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ 1.3545958543110964e-01, -2.0383389968255977e-01, 0., 0., 0. ]
M2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 4.6716183686593592e+02, 0., 3.1321301298488936e+02, 0.,
       4.6716183686593592e+02, 2.7674405764548516e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ 6.8017486649835202e-02, -1.2178761345435389e-01, 0., 0., 0. ]
```

My extrinsics matrix:

```
%YAML:1.0
R: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 9.9771868227118155e-01, -7.5673210589346316e-03,
       6.7083281814831405e-02, 8.9579410266375625e-03,
       9.9975067896491787e-01, -2.0453244284196821e-02,
       -6.6911780275377294e-02, 2.1007512017769996e-02,
       9.9753771763237242e-01 ]
T: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -3.7118950200284830e+00, 2.0057520035877928e-02,
       -1.1958455121942886e-01 ]
R1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 9.9498387348418538e-01, -1.2286209661821963e-02,
       9.9278097073585744e-02, 1.3314580062505074e-02,
       9.9986428207583911e-01, -9.7025453735457880e-03,
       -9.9145415749623558e-02, 1.0975722350366061e-02,
       9.9501242206050977e-01 ]
R2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 9.9946687339085338e-01, -5.4006987617013216e-03,
       3.2199401348428379e-02, 5.0670326515128601e-03,
       9.9993271463178834e-01, 1.0435103699094591e-02,
       -3.2253591651478383e-02, -1.0266385049651746e-02,
       9.9942698941122865e-01 ]
P1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 4
   dt: d
   data: [ 4.2226276527153402e+02, 0., 2.8740816497802734e+02, 0., 0.,
       4.2226276527153402e+02, 2.7487768363952637e+02, 0., 0., 0., 1.,
       0. ]
P2: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 4
   dt: d
   data: [ 4.2226276527153402e+02, 0., 2.8740816497802734e+02,
       -1.5682311212949173e+03, 0., 4.2226276527153402e+02,
       2.7487768363952637e+02, 0., 0., 0., 1., 0. ]
Q: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 4
   cols: 4
   dt: d
   data: [ 1., 0., 0., -2.8740816497802734e+02, 0., 1., 0.,
       -2.7487768363952637e+02, 0., 0., 0., 4.2226276527153402e+02, 0.,
       0., -2.6926054427670321e-01, 0. ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing in OpenCV.  But you can, in principle, take your calibration data into matlab, and manually construct a `cameraParameters` object, which you can then pass into `showExtrinsics()`.

Comment: Seems like I'll resort to piping the data into matlab then - thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the cameraCalibrator app in Matlab directly?

Comment: I would have liked to integrate the visualization solution into our Python/C++ codebase - not an option to use Matlab's calibrator. At any rate, I only need a handful of OpenCV function calls to calculate a calibration (mainly findChessBoardCorners, stereoRectify) so it wouldn't save me any time to calibrate with Matlab. For debugging purposes however Matlab should suffice.